# How to combine objects with function properties? JS

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I've the following js code, where I've 2 constants, that receives an object. Both objects have function properties. And we can see too that they've repeated code. onApprove, onError, and onCancel properties are repeated.

What I seek is: How can I mix both together in a new const, and then both of those objects will inherit the new const + extra properties. So I'll have a total of 3 consts, where in the new one I'll have the repeated code with onApprove, onError and onCancel and the PaypalSubscription and PaypalOffer consts will only have the createSubscription and createOrder respectively.

I've tried some concepts but nothing worked so far.

Any idea on how to do this? Thank you!

```
const PaypalSubscription = {
  createSubscription(data, actions) {
    ...
  },

  onApprove(res) {
    return postCallback('approve', res);
  },
  onError(res) {
    return postCallback('cancel', res);
  },
  onCancel(res) {
    return postCallback('cancel', res);
  },
}

const PaypalOffer = {
  createOrder(data, { order }) {
    ...
  },
  onApprove(res) {
    return postCallback('approve', res);
  },
  onError(res) {
    return postCallback('cancel', res);
  },
  onCancel(res) {
    return postCallback('cancel', res);
  },
};
```

Comment: Making a base class with the shared methods, that two other classes extend, seems like a decent approach

Comment: Otherwise you could pull the shared methods out to another object variable and later `Object.assign` them into the other two objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need classes there, go with objects:

```js
const commonProps = {
  onApprove(res) {
    return postCallback('approve', res);
  },
  onError(res) {
    return postCallback('cancel', res);
  },
  onCancel(res) {
    return postCallback('cancel', res);
  },
}
const PaypalSubscription = {
  ...commonProps,
  createSubscription(data, actions) {
    // do something
  },
}

const PaypalOffer = {
  ...commonProps,
  createOrder(data, { order }) {
    // do something
  },
};
```

Comment: I would swear that I did exactly this solution, using the spread operator. I'll try again, probably I mess something up.

Answer (score 0):

> *"we can see too that they've repeated code"*

If you have repeated code, you may want to take a look at Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) principles.

> *"both of those objects will inherit"*

If you want the object to inherit methods, then use real OOP inheritance.

```js
class PaypalTransaction {
  onApprove(res) {
    return this.postCallback('approve', res);
  }
  onError(res) {
    return this.postCallback('cancel', res);
  }
  onCancel(res) {
    return this.postCallback('cancel', res);
  }
  postCallback(status, res) {
    console.log(`${status}`);
  }
}

class PaypalSubscription extends PaypalTransaction {
  createSubscription(data, actions) {
    // ...
  }
}

class PaypalOffer extends PaypalTransaction {
  createOrder(data, { order }) {
    // ...
  }
}

const transactions = [
  new PaypalSubscription(),
  new PaypalOffer()
];

transactions.forEach(tx => tx.onApprove('foo'));
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't touch in OOP for some years, need to revisit some concepts again. But I do remember inheritance, and your code already revived some hidden knowledge. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for either the spread operator (...) [ES6 feature] or Object.Assign().

```
const SubscribeBase = {
   createSubscription(data, actions) {
      ...
   }
};

const OfferBase = {
   createOrder(data, { order }) {
      ...
   }      
};

const ResponseBase = {
   onApprove(res) {
      return postCallback('approve', res);
   },
   onError(res) {
     return postCallback('cancel', res);
   },
   onCancel(res) {
     return postCallback('cancel', res);
   }
}

const PaypalSubscription = {
   ...SubscribeBase,
   ...ResponseBase
}

const PaypalOffer = {
   ...OfferBase,
   ...ResponseBase
}
```

A good tutorial can be found here [Merge Objects](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/javascript-merge-objects/)